# SQL JOIN, all from t1 and all from t2 except what's common to t1

Tags: sql, join, presto

I need all entries from Table A and all entries from Table B that are NOT common to table A. I have 6 common fields. How do I go with this? I tried select ... from Table A left join Table B, it missed some values from Table A. Tried also right join, full join...Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Any non-common columns?

Comment: How you are determining common rows between t2 and t1? With a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?  Assuming that `a` and `b` have the same columns:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1
                  from a
                  where a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and . . .
                 );
```

EDIT:

SparkSQL should support `not exists`, but you can write it using `left join` instead:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b left join
     a
     on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and . . .
where a.col1 is null;
```

Comment: I am using sparksql, is there an equivalent for not exists? and what does select 1 do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way to do this is using a `UNION` operator like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM TableA)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TableB);
```

The union operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more `SELECT` statements.